# Custom asyncvalidator is not getting executed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am trying to create an angular asyncValidator but I think I am doing something wrong becausse it does not get executed.Here is my code:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('project')
    .directive('imageValidator', imageValidator);

imageValidator.$inject = ['utilitiesService', '$q'];

function imageValidator(utilitiesService, $q) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.imageValidator = function (url) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (url) {
                var image = new Image();

                if (utilitiesService.isNotExternalFile(url)) {
                    image.src = utilitiesService.getUrl(url)
                } else {
                    image.src = url;
                }

                image.onload = function () {
                    deferred.resolve(true);
                    scope.$apply();
                }

                image.onerror = function () {
                    deferred.reject(false);
                    scope.$apply();
                }

            } else {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
     }
  }
})();
```

The code gets executed oance but it does not get executed when I change things in the input.

When it first gets executed it sets the class ng-valid-image-validator which is correct I want it to be valid if there is nothing in the input.

But when I write something in the input ng-valid-image-validator gets removed but it does not add the ng-invalid-image-validator and I asume this happens because the custom validator code does not get executed.

Does anyone have any ideeas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT** : I just noticed that the validator gets executed again if emptying the input.

Comment: `image.onload() = function () {` => `image.onload = function () {`

Comment: I made the change but it still does not execute